# How to perform integration test on android (or how to get and inject several components in TestCase)

Tags: android, testing, service, integration-testing

I have an application which has some services which communicate to each other. All of them work in a single process so they don't need a Messenger. While application runs, my main service connects to other ones and injects services as dependencies. For example ImportService needs ParserService to perform some operations and so ImportService has method setParserService(ParserService service);

It works fine at real operation but I can't run tests for services which need dependencies, because ServiceTestCase.bindService() only knows how to start/bind a service which it actually tests. It can't start/bind other service which I need as a dependency. It compiles when I try to get an other service but crashes while trying to call bindService().

I've googled a lot but now I can see only three ways of solving it:

- Make an application more primitive. Use just classes instead of services;
- Not to make injections. Get dependencies inside of a service instead. But this way I'll have to wait while dependencies(services) are bound at some places inside of a service. It will be a bad code. I can't use onServiceConnected() because sometimes I may need more than one service as a dependency.
- Not to use tests :-)

**So, briefly, the question is:** I can bind one specific service in a test by using ServiceTestCase. But how can I bind 2, 10 or more services in one test?

Comment: I've tried the second of three ways which I wrote upper - made waiting for a service in a service's tested method. It's a bad practice but it works. But I still can't use it in my project because it works only when all of my services run in the main application process. Normally I run all the services in one separate process. Now I'm searching how to make my test run in a proper process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ServiceTestCase** provides a framework in which you can test Service classes in a controlled environment. It provides basic support for the lifecycle of **a [single] Service**, and hooks with which you can inject various dependencies and control the environment in which your Service is tested.

If you are performing integration test of various Services you should test them as part of the **Activity** or **Application** using them.